# Compare array of datetime objects and pick all rows where difference between each and the next is less than 7 days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ansi-sql

My table looks like this:

[image: Link to screenshot of my table] (can't post images yet)

I want to select all names from my table where the time difference between each of the datetime objects and the next is always more than 7 days.
So from the above I would get only Paul, since Adam's first two times are already only a day apart.

The best I can come up with is to get the time difference between the smallest and largest datetime in the array and then divide by array_length(datetime). So basically the average time all datetime objects, but that's not helping me.

I'm using Standard SQL on BigQuery

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM dataset.table
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(datetime) AS dt WITH OFFSET off
  WHERE DATETIME_DIFF(
    datetime[SAFE_OFFSET(off - 1)], dt, DAY
  ) <= 7
)
```

This compares each entry in the array with the one after it, looking for any where the number of days is 7 or less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from (select dt, lag(dt) over (order by dt) as prev_dt
                        from unnest(datetime) dt
                       ) x
                  where dt < datetime_add(prev_dt, interval 7 day
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear what exactly the schema of your data: based on layout  - it looks like datetime is an array, but based on data type you show in the image - it could be just regular field, so below cover both cases (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

> Case 1 - repeated field

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 7 < (
    SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(
      datetime, 
      LAG(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY datetime), 
      DAY) distance
    FROM UNNEST(datetime) datetime 
    ORDER BY IFNULL(distance, 777)
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

you can test, play with it using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Adam' name, 
    [DATETIME '2018-07-26T17:55:03', 
      '2018-07-27T17:55:03',
      '2018-06-29T17:55:03',
      '2018-07-16T17:55:03',
      '2018-08-19T17:55:03',
      '2018-07-14T17:55:03'] datetime UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Paul', [DATETIME '2018-08-26T17:55:03',
      '2018-08-18T17:55:03',
      '2018-06-20T17:55:03',
      '2018-08-09T17:55:03',
      '2018-07-16T17:55:03']
)
SELECT name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 7 < (
    SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(
      datetime, 
      LAG(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY datetime), 
      DAY) distance
    FROM UNNEST(datetime) datetime 
    ORDER BY IFNULL(distance, 777)
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

> Case 2 - regular (not repeated field)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT name, 
    DATETIME_DIFF(
      datetime, 
      LAG(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY datetime), 
      DAY
    ) distance
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY name 
HAVING MIN(distance) > 7
```

Dummy data example below:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Adam' name, DATETIME '2018-07-26T17:55:03' datetime UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Adam', '2018-07-27T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Adam', '2018-06-29T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Adam', '2018-07-16T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Adam', '2018-08-19T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Adam', '2018-07-14T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Paul', '2018-08-26T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Paul', '2018-08-18T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Paul', '2018-06-20T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Paul', '2018-08-09T17:55:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Paul', '2018-07-16T17:55:03' 
)
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT name, 
    DATETIME_DIFF(
      datetime, 
      LAG(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY datetime), 
      DAY
    ) distance
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY name 
HAVING MIN(distance) > 7
```

both return same result

```sql
Row name     
1   Paul
```